# Using SQL to find the list of items sold frequently

Tags: mysql, sql

DB: Mysql

Given a very large table with structure

```
purchase_date
account_id
Product_id
```

Find the frequently purchased product ids.
By frequently it means, the product has to be bought at least twice in a duration of 3 days.

eg: dummy values

```
purchase_date  product_id  account_id
01-04-2016      P1          A1
05-04-2016      P2          A1
06-04-2016      P2          A1
06-04-2016      P1          A1
```

The query should return only P2 and not P1.

Comment: group by, having count(*) >= 2.

Comment: This was asked in an interview. We could take Oracle or mysql for example @jarlh how do i ensure that the count > 2 falls between 3 consecutive days.

Comment: Those two products have their own sets of date/time functions.

Comment: Oops, I read "last 3 days". Do a self join instead, condition between 3 consecutive days.

Comment: In Oracle this is quite easy with a count() over the previous three days using a window function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you paste the query for my understanding pls?

Comment: @jarlh select p1.product_id from products p1 join products p2 on p1.product_id = p2.product_id where datediff(p1.purchase_date,p2.purchase_date)=3 and count(p1.product_id) >= 2  is this valid? i am not sure how to put the count thing.

Comment: You can skip the count(*) if you do a self join. Just make sure you're not comparing a row with itself.

Comment: here is an example considering only consecutive days: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d42fa/1 (but this won't work on MySQL as it doesn't support modern SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT  P1.product_id
FROM    products P1
    INNER JOIN products P2 ON P1.product_id = P2.product_id 
WHERE   DATEDIFF(P2.purchase_date,P1.purchase_date) >= 3
GROUP BY P1.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: All products will be selected because of self join

Comment: Products with match WHERE clause and HAVING clause only, can u plz explain the case "All products will be selected" ?

Comment: 1."since the self join will include itself" in this case the datediff should not be >=3, 2."the date comparison seems inverted" and using datdiff(P2,P1) instead of (P1,P2). if required both can be changed, its not a final query , because i don't have any schema or data, this just a logic, he can modify this as per their requirement.